# Gensim - how to deal with model word::tag

Tags: load, gensim, corpus

I'm trying to load a pretrained word2vec model using gensim. Although the model is tagged, so every word has a tag, which tells what part of speech is this word represents.

For example:

`big::adj 0.041660 0.045049 -0.204449 0.102298 0.045326 -0.172079 0.197417 -0.012363 0.127003 0.040437 -0.003397 0.048288 0.072291 0.044205 -0.055407 -0.075357 -0.154024 0.021732 0.224021 -0.243452 -0.048776 -0.002823 0.110283 -0.052014 0.104335 -0.108122 -0.033678 -0.098096 -0.012307 0.086673 -0.028013 0.005308 -0.196080 0.002180 -0.004461 0.021646 -0.051721 -0.123485 -0.230521 0.106092 -0.206776 0.137945 0.020572 0.071123 0.042434 0.123633 -0.001925 -0.172347 -0.040973 0.135886 0.057297 -0.027319 0.066697 0.138673 -0.028331 -0.094053 -0.160371 0.158397 0.053368 -0.002126 -0.111501 0.030450 -0.054284 -0.004832 -0.065144 0.030546 -0.011896 -0.103835 -0.007947 0.120997 0.178889 -0.155029 -0.054059 -0.313675 0.061776 -0.060536 0.038848 -0.097532 -0.038358 -0.032634 0.108534 0.067584 0.044829 0.003414 0.028115 -0.010523 0.131776 0.071750 0.045095 0.046262 0.001212 -0.005994 -0.022401 -0.036971 -0.024755 0.096701 -0.026736 -0.029698 -0.107293 -0.038610`

Can anyone point me out, how to load such a model, so I can ask for model['big']? Right now, it just doesn't work, when I try KeyedVectors.load().

Comment: Where did your model come from? I would guess you have to tag the words before you try to get vectors for them, so you have to `model['big::adj']` instead of `model['big']`.

Comment: The model comes from:
https://clarin-pl.eu/dspace/handle/11321/327

Answer (score 0):

As indicated in your sample data, you have to give the words a part of speech tag before using them. From the README (`opis.txt`) included with your vectors:

```
Tzn że w samym modelu znajdują się słowa zapisane w następujący sposób:
    lemmat::pos np. pszczoła::noun
```

Google translated:

```
That is, in the model itself there are words written in the following way:
    lemma :: pos eg. bee :: noun
```

The README also provides a list of valid parts of speech.

Because the word vectors were trained this way, there is no valid vector for a word without a part of speech.

If you want a vector without part of speech for some reason, you could loop over all the possible parts of speech and take an average of the vectors like this:

```py
vectors = pretrained_vectors
word = 'bee'
parts_of_speech = ['noun', 'verb', etc...]
vec = zero_vector
pos_count = 0
for part in parts_of_speech:
    key = word + '::' + part
    if key in vectors:
        vec += vectors[word + '::' + part]
        pos_count += 1

vec = vec / pos_count
# if actually using code like this, use numpy and watch for zero division
```

That said I suspect the resulting vectors could have issues. A better option is to find pre-trained vectors that don't use part of speech, such as [those provided with Fasttext](https://github.com/facebookresearch/fastText/blob/master/docs/crawl-vectors.md).